# Get phrase from middle of a string between two particular characters

Tags: php, string, substring, text-extraction

I want to extract a portion of a string between two points in a string.

My input string is `{you: awesome; feeling good}`

I want to get the words `feeling good` between `;` and `}` using PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = explode(';', trim("{you: awesome; feeling good}", '{}'));
$feel_good_string = trim($arr[1]);
echo $feel_good_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in PHP for split string.

**Example 1:**

```
$string = '{you: awesome; feeling good}'; // your string
preg_match('/{(.*?)}/', $string, $match); // match inside the {}
$exploded = explode(";",$match[1]); // explode with ;
echo $exploded[1]; // feeling good
```

**Example 2:**

```
$string = '{you: awesome; feeling good}'; // your string
$exploded = explode(";", $string);  // explode with ;
echo rtrim($exploded[1],"}"); // rtrim to remove ending }
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be....

```
$str = "{you: awesome; feeling good}";
$str = trim($str,"{}");
echo substr($str,strpos($str,";")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a regex pattern, you avoid needing to generate a temporary array or performing separate extraction and sanitization steps.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vAjua))

```
$string = "{you: awesome; feeling good}";
echo preg_replace('/[^;]*; ([^}]*).*/', '$1', $string);
// feeling good
```

The pattern matches the entire string.

Start matching zero or more non-semicolon characters, then a space.
Then capture zero or more non-closing-parenthesis characters.
Then match the rest of the string.
Replace the full string with the captured middle segment.